# IE caches dynamically added iframe. Why, and how do I prevent it?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, dom, cross-browser

I have the following HTML / JS:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      function foo(){
        var html = "<iframe src=\"foo.html\" />";
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML=html;
      }

      function bar(){
        var html = "<iframe src=\"bar.html\" />";
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML=html;
      }

      function show(){
        alert(document.getElementById('content').innerHTML);
      }
    </script>
    <button onclick="foo()">foo</button><br />
    <button onclick="bar()">bar</button><br />
    <button onclick="show()">test</button><br />    

    <div id="content"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This sort of works as expected, even in IE. Until I hit F5. When I first click *foo*, I get an iframe with the contents of `foo.html`, as expected. I then refresh, and hit *bar*. Instead of getting the contents of `bar.html`, I see the contents of `foo.html`. Strangely, when I click *test*, the `alert()` tells me the `src` attribute for the iframe is correctly set to `bar.html`. Firefox has no such issue.

Why does this happen, and how do I prevent it?

***edit:*** what I forgot to mention is that I can't put the iframe in and change the src attribute. In the real situation I have, sometimes I need an `<img>` rather than an `<iframe>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried changing the url in your generated iframe?
E.g.

```
var randomNum = Math.random();
var html = "<iframe src=\"bar.html?rand="+randomNum+"\" />";
```

Even better, combine that with geowa4's appendChild() suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Use this DOM

```
<div id="content" style='display:none;'>

  <iframe id='contentFrame' src='' />

</div>
```

And this as your script

```
function foo() {
  var contentDiv = document.getElementById('content');
  var contentFrame = document.getElementById('contentFrame');

  contentFrame.src = 'foo.html';
  contentDiv.style.display='block';
}
```

I have noticed some weird behavior with IE and using innerHTML.  I would only use it to clear the contents (innerHTML = "").  If I want to add anything, I use HTMLElement.appendChild(); it hasn't failed for me yet.

Answer (score 2):

Set the SRC of the Iframe instead of changing the innerHTML of its container:

html:

```
<iframe id="myFrame" src="about:blank" />
```

script:

```
document.getElementById('myFrame').src='foo.html'
```